# Stop app from showing multiple icons in Dock

Tags: dock

is showing up multiple times in the Dock. It's only open once. How do i stop this?

I have opened an app once, but it shows up two more times in a different middle section between two lines.

[image]

Is this an app misbehaviour or an macOS one? I can't tell and I'm not sure where to troubleshoot. This is the only app it happens with.

Comment: What app is it?

Comment: Are you running macOS Mojave?

Comment: What happens when you try to drag the other ones out of the dock?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apps with support for opening documents minimize into Dock in their own separate icon. To disable that behaviour, check **Minimise windows into application icon** under System Preferences → Dock.

macOS Mojave has a configuration to show recently used app's icon in the Dock (just like in iOS 11 and later). To disable it, uncheck **Show recent applications in Dock** under System Preferences → Dock.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can't believe i didn't notice this was a thing sooner